# How can I have a div external to the scrolling div to follow?

Tags: html, css, web

First, example JS fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d63d2zok/
Code on JS fiddle for easier ref:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 248px; width:40px; height: 40px; background: green; z-index: 200"></div>
    <div style="background: black; height: 10000px; width: 300px">
        <div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll">
            <div style="background: blue; height: 1000px; vertical-align: middle">
            <textarea style="vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 200px"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem:
If we scroll on the black div, we can see that the green square follows the page - 10/10 would do again
But, if we scroll on the blue div, we can see the green square does not follow. 10/10 CSS and HTML doing its job, since the green square div is actually defined outside the blue div.
My dilemma is that I want to make it so the green square follows the blue div when scrolling, without moving the div inside the blue div. Is this possible? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer:  not with just css

long answer:  you can wire a javascript function to alter to position of the green div based on the offset of the blue div, e.g.:

```
document
  .getElementById('theBlueDiv')
  .addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    document
      .getElementById('theGreenDiv')
      .style
      .top = (yourOriginalGreenDivTopValue - e.target.scrollY) + 'px';
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution with pure CSS / HTML, but I suppose that's not possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try position: fixed; and top:10px; on green div.

Comment: Position fixed will force the green div to stay at the same place regardless of scrolling though, unfortunately not what I want. I was hoping to have the green div follow the text area

Comment: So why we need position absolute then?

Why not this?
https://jsfiddle.net/15w4Lxv8/
I'm bit confused here

Comment: I want to move the div inside too, but it's actually not feasible to do it in production. Thanks though!